# Grunt compiled-scripts doesn't seem to be including newly created controller

Tags: ember.js, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

Totally new to Yeoman/Grunt/Bower/Ember setup so if this is a stupid question, sorry in advance.  I successfully setup Yeoman, and I just tried to add my first controller.

I did it manually, just creating a new file w/in the controller directory, and refreshed my page to see that the **controller file seemed to not be included in the `compiled-scripts` file.**

I thought, "Hm, maybe it needs to be compiled or built or something... so I ran `grunt` and `grunt build`, served the application again and still, no luck.  Is there some kind of `grunt` command or process in installing ember controllers that I missed?